# AddEventListener to svg file and not button that makes it clickable

Tags: javascript, html, svg, click, addeventlistener

Here is my objective :
I want to have a button on my html page that when it is clicked, makes and svg clickable, and when that svg is clicked, the page displays the message "clicked".

I have an html file where I create a button and a div that holds an svg file :

**HTML File**

```
*....*

 <div>
        <p>This will be replaced <br/>
            <span id="id_to_be_replaced" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"> Replaced normally </span>.</p>
</div>

*....*

<br />
        <input name="button5" type="button" id="myButton5" onClick="button5_makeClickable('svgfile');" value="4. Svg clickable" />
<br />

*....*

<div>
        <object id="svgfile" data = "exemple.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> </object> 
</div>
```

What I want is that when I press my button5 it is supposed to make the svg file clickable, the function that I call are in another javascript file :

**JS File**

```
*....*

function setName(name) {
    var elementHtmltoFill = window.document.getElementById("id_to_be_replaced");
    elementHtmltoFill.innerHTML = name;
}

*....*

function button5_makeClickable(id) {
    var drawing = document.getElementById('svgfile'); 
    drawing.addEventListener('click', setName("clicked"));
}

*....*
```

However what happens is that "clicked" is displayed as soon as I click on the button (and not the svg).
I don't understand why since I add the event listener to drawing (therefore the svg)?

Thank you for your help !

PS : I am trying to understand the use of the function addEventListener, so I would prefer if your help uses it please.

Comment: on your button5_makeClickable you are calling the setName function directly try to wrap it in arrow function 
like this 
drawing.addEventListener('click', () => setName("clicked"));

Answer (score 0):

By doing `setName("clicked")` you instantly call the `setName` function instead of passing a reference to the function. You can solve this passing a function as the event handler argument in which you call `setName("clicked")`.

```
function button5_makeClickable(id) {
    var drawing = document.getElementById('svgfile'); 
    drawing.addEventListener('click', function() {
      setName("clicked")
    });
}
```

But, your code currently is constantly adding event listeners to the `<object>` element. The element only needs 1 click event listener.

Use a *flag*. This a boolean (true / false) which acts like a switch to do or to not do something based on its value. Add a event listener to the `<object>` element and check in the event handler if the flag is `true`. If it is, change the text inside your span, if it isn't, don't do anything.

The example below shows how this could work.

Also, prevent using inline event listeners in your HTML. Using `addEventListener` is the way you should be learning how to attach event handlers.

```js
var myButton5 = document.getElementById('myButton5');
var drawing = document.getElementById('svgfile');
var svgIsClickable = false;

function setName(name) {
  var elementHtmltoFill = window.document.getElementById("id_to_be_replaced");
  console.log(elementHtmltoFill)
  elementHtmltoFill.innerHTML = name;
}

function button5_makeClickable(event) {
  svgIsClickable = true;
}

myButton5.addEventListener('click', button5_makeClickable);
drawing.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (svgIsClickable === true) {
    setName("clicked");
  }
});
```

```css
object {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This will be replaced <br/>
    <span id="id_to_be_replaced" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"> Replaced normally </span>.</p>
</div>

<br />
<input name="button5" type="button" id="myButton5" onClick="button5_makeClickable" value="4. Svg clickable" />
<br />

<div>
  <object id="svgfile" data="exemple.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  "clicked" is not displayed when i press the button anymore so that problem is solved. However, if I click on the image (corresponding to the svg) nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure you listener for the svgfile object is outside the onclick function for your button otherwise you can only ever click on the svgfile object whenever you are simultaneously clicking on the button.

Comment: Do you mean that the onclick function should call another function that adds the even listener to the svgfile?

Comment: You should have two onclick listeners. One for the button, and one for svgfile object. When the listener for the button gets a response it could change a variable to "true" for example. Then when your seperate listener for the object gets a response the function it runs should check if the variable is true. If it is true then run the code.